# Replacing itemize by mdwlist's itemize* throughout?

Tags: environments, itemize, lists

Most of my documents start with a couple of quick hacks that save me literally a couple of keystrokes a month:

```
\let\cite\texcite
\let\epsilon\varepsilon
```

and so on.
Now, I'd like to do a similar thing to globally have my `itemize` environments behave like the `itemize*` environment defined by the `mdwlist` package. This is a little trickier, because itemize is an environment, not a command.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, in such cases we could achieve it by

```
\let\newname\name
\let\endnewname\endname
```

or `\renewenvironment`.

But here it's not this simple, since the old environment would still be used. We would easily end up with `TeX capacity exceeded` because of nesting. A solution is to store the old environment in another macro, afterwards we could refer to that. Or easier, use the `\makecompactlist` command of mdwlist to redefine the original itemize environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\let\stditemize\itemize
\let\endstditemize\enditemize
\let\itemize\undefined
\makecompactlist{itemize}{stditemize}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The compact output list:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Wrong answer** (in this case):

If this is LaTeX, then in general something like

```
\renewenvironment{itemize}{\begin{itemize*}}{\end{itemize*}}
```

should do the trick. However in this case it will cause nesting problems if `itemize*` internally uses `itemize`. (Thanks, Stefan)

Comment: This standard method is not working here, it causes too deep nesting.

Comment: Added a remark to the answer. I'll leave the answer so that nobody else wastes time by trying this answer.