# Customize line-spacing and indentation of a list in LyX

Tags: lists, lyx, indentation, itemize, line-spacing

I am currently using a list with bullet-points; however, I think the lines are spaces too far apart and they're indented way too much. I don't see any way to correct this in LyX, however.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding the following code to your LaTeX preamble:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}
```

You can edit the Latex preamble under Document > Settings, under the LaTeX Preamble tab.

Cf. [Remove space around bullet points in itemized or enumerated list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/825/remove-space-around-bullet-points-in-itemized-or-enumerated-list).  You can make the vertical separation affect only bullet point lists (and not, say description lists), by using `\setitemize` instead of `\setlist`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to `\usepackage{mdwlist}` and then use the `itemize*` environment defined by that package: it automatically shrinks the spacing between list items.

To use this solution with LyX, you'll apparently need to redefine the actual `itemize` environment using the solution in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/replacing-itemize-by-mdwlists-itemize-throughout/1604#1604)

Comment: You'll need to put a `\renewenvironment` to the latex preamble, to make `\itemize` use `\itemize*`, since Lyx's bellut lists are defined using `\itemize`.

Comment: That doesn't work. See here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/replacing-itemize-by-mdwlists-itemize-throughout/1604#1604

Comment: Ah!  So `mdwliists`'s `itemize*` is a wrapper around `itemize`.  But Stefan's solution will do the job here.

Comment: mdwlist is outdated. Enumitem is the up-to-date package to use.